# C++ Unable to Read Memory Address

Tags: c++, cheat-engine

I'm creating a simple HACK for educational purpose only. A simple Triggerbot that reads from memory the value of player aiming to enemy YES = 1 or NO = 0. I have made some other similar HACKS however I never found  this problem .. in Rainbow Six Siege I have the memory address both static or dynamic however cheat engine read it well but when I try to read it from my C++ Program it does't work. Not sure why if it had work with other games. I'm new to this and maybe I did something wrong.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#define F6Key 0x75
using namespace std ;
int value ;
int main()
{
    cout << "Open Game .." << endl ;
    system("Pause") ;
    LPCWSTR gameone = L"Rainbow Six";
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, gameone);
    if (gameone == 0)
    {
        cout << "Not Found." << endl ;
        system("Pause") ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Success finding game." << endl;
        DWORD processid ;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processid) ;
        HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processid) ;
        cout << processid ;

        if (!ReadProcessMemory(process, (void *)0x25421AD9D6C, (void *)&value, sizeof(value), NULL)) {
            cout << "Unable to read memory proccess";
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n Read: " << value;
        }
        system("Pause");
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Here is the code simple Find the Window by name, gets its PID fine no problem. OpenProcess then when I call the method ReadProcessMemory with the process, address pointer value by parameter is unable to read it print the if condition and never the else of value read.

If I remove the function from the If condition just for testing if at least points to something it gives some random values... is weird that I'm unable to read memory It always work ::( 
Can someone help me out? It is some king of security software or something?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check `OpenProcess` return value. If your process does not have sufficient rights, it will return `NULL` and any attempts to use this handle will fail. Use `GetLastError` function to determine error reason.
Most likely it will be `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Secondary, to successfully access external process memory space, you should open its handle with `PROCESS_VM_READ` right or enable `seDebugPrivilege` for you process token. Example how to do that you could see in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And lastly. If memory address (`0x25421AD9D6C` in your case) is invalid, `ReadProcessMemory` will fail. In that case `value` variable would not be initialized and any attempts to use it is an undefined behavior.

Also, if you managed to get process handle, it should be closed using `CloseHandle` function when you finish using it.

**Upd:** If `ReadProcessMemory` returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError` - `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` that means that a page fault has occured, you are trying to read from a buffer and at least part of it is not assigned to the physical memory. If you know your value offset, get module load address using PSAPI `GetModuleInformation` function and add offset to the `lpBaseOfDll` field of the `MODULEINFO` structure.

Comment: OK This is the base address without the Offsets. "RainbowSix.exe"+06090F50 . I run the GetLastError method and I'm getting Error 299 Partial copy meaning: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx